# Generalization of Euler four square formula?

Tags: nt.number-theory

It is well known that the number of distinct decompositions of a positive natural number N into sum of four squares of integers is equal to 8*sum(d : d|N and not(4|d))

In other words, this is the number of distinct integer solutions of the quadratic form

x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=N

How do I count solutions for more general quadratic forms?

For my purposes it suffice to limit the question to diagonal forms

a*x^2+b*y^2+c*z^2+d*w^2=N

In fact if it helps to simplify the question. The specific instance of interest right now is

x^2+y^2+z^2+2*w^2=2^L , where L is an integer.

Thanks,
Alex--

Comment: For a general quadratic form one can get only an approximate formula
with an error term coming form a coefficient of some modular cusp form.
But your diagonal form $x^2+y^2+z^2+2w^2$ should still be simple enough
that, as with the sum of four squares, the only cusp form is zero so that the
approximation is exact.  For $x^2+y^2+z^2+2w^2 = 2^L$ the count seems to be
$2^{L+3}-2$.

Answer (score 6):

The representation numbers for your specific quaternary quadratic form are determined in Theorem 5.1 of this paper by Alaca^2, Lemire, and Williams:

http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/330.pdf

In particular, that theorem confirms the conjecture Noam made in the comments. For related results, see also this paper

http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/310.pdf

and the references therein.